# Is it Better to Use a Separate VPS for Each Website or Have One, Stronger VPS?

Tags: web-hosting, vps, linux

In what situations should one purchase multiple VPSes to host multiple websites? For instance, renting three VPSes with 1GB RAM 3 times vs renting one VPS with 3GB RAM?

The problem I am currently having with multiple VPSes is that I have to setup a lot of configurations on each, and as they generally all need email (PostFix), LAMP and the same Apache configurations, I'm finding it very frustrating to use.

Therefore the top priority is going to be performance and ease of maintainance.

Which path shall I take? I appreciate all opinions with points backed up.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, it depends on the load the VPS's will be under.  If you run high-traffic sites with memory-hogging applications (*hello, un-optimized WordPress in an un-optimized environment...how YOU doin'?*), keeping each VPS separate is probably the better idea so that if one site gets a traffic spike or other load-causing event and causes a server slowdown your other sites are still up and running.

But if these are small sites with not a ton of traffic and you know how to tune both application and server resources properly, then it should be far more time and cost-effective to get one beefy server instead of dealing with a ton of identical VPS's.

Comment: +1 As always, informative and entertaining. I'd only add that performance doesn't always go hand-in-hand with ease of maintenance. You could use a control panel with migration tools to help move domains/accounts from one virtual server to multiple ones later on as needed.

Comment: @dan Yes.  But this would then devolve into a *reductio ad absurdum* answer as we would have to cover every possible combination of VPS offerings, control panels, and administrative competence levels.  I'm not surprised it got put on hold.

Comment: Not sure why all that would need to follow...but yes, I would have closed it if not already. I like to see people get credit though for good answers, even if the question is deemed off-topic.

Comment: It would have followed mainly due to my insanity and attempts to provide a really complete answer.  Plus, New Year's whisky.

Comment: Haa, haven't seen any "inspired" answers yet, unfortunately.